# Looping in a list and setting colors on items according the length of the items is not working

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I have a problem, my code should check the length of items in my list and set color, if the item is longer than 6, color on that item should be red else blue but it returns all items red.

```
    function onS() {
    var item = "";
    var itemLength = 0;

    var Enum = listItems.getEnumerator();
    while (Enum.moveNext()) {
        var currentItem = Enum.get_current();
        item += "<br/>" + currentItem.get_item("Title");

        if (item.length > itemLength) {
            itemLength = item.length;
            if (itemLength > 6) {
                document.getElementById("items").style.color = "red";
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById("items").style.color = "blue";
            }
        }
        $("#items").html(item);
    }   
}
```

Comment: is this in sharepoint ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee659727(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Yes. I am looping in a SP list

Comment: @abc Does the `Title` have ID or Classname?

Comment: @Chris Beckett it has ID

Comment: @Chris Beckett every item in a list has an ID. 1,2,3,4 etc.

Comment: @Chris Beckett Title is just a column name and I have many items there and every item has an unique ID

Answer (score 2):

with

```
var itemLength = 0;
while ... {
   if (item.length > itemLength) {
        itemLength = item.length;
```

You say that you will enter the loop only if the current item is longer than the prévious one. So if your first item has the max length, you will never enter the loop for any other item.

Also you wrote

```
document.getElementById("items").style.color = "red";
```

That means that you have only one element with id="items" because ids have to be uniques. So it doesn't make sense to change one color so many times. You probably want to do :

```
$(item).style.color = "red";
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing some code which makes this annoying to test. I think the issue is regarding this though:

```
item += "<br/>" + currentItem.get_item("Title");
```

Are you sure that currentItem.get_item("Title").length + "
".length isn't always > 6?

You could change it to only look at `currentItem.get_item("Title").length`

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById("items")` set the text color of all children of the DOM node with the id "items".

I think you want to successively only specify the color of the DOM node designed by the `item` variable.

You need to put this item in a separate node, e.g. a `span`, then set the style color of this node. This obviously impact the length you are measuring. But I feel like what you are actually trying to look at is the length of your item's title and not the length of the whole html code of `items` like you are doing here.

```
var items = $("#items");
var itemLength = 0;

while (Enum.moveNext()) {
  var currentItem = Enum.get_current();
  var title = currentItem.get_item("Title");
  var currentItemNode = $("<span>" + title + "</span>");
  items.append("<br/>");
  items.append(currentItemNode);

  if (title.length > itemLength) {
    itemLength = item.length;
    if (itemLength > 6) {
        currentItemNode.css("color", "red");
    } else {
        currentItemNode.css("color", "blue");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed. Thanks for any help!

```
function onS() {
var item = "";
var item1 = "";

var Enum = listItems.getEnumerator();
while (Enum.moveNext()) {
    var currentItem = Enum.get_current();

    if(currentItem.get_item("Title").length>6){

        document.getElementById("items").style.color = "red";
        item += "<br/>" + currentItem.get_item("Title");
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("items1").style.color = "blue";
        item1 += "<br/>" + currentItem.get_item("Title");
    }
 }
$("#items").html(item);
$("#items1").html(item1);
```